# Add pre-payment option to woocommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I added a checkbox input before proceeding to payment gateways using this hook: `woocommerce_review_order_before_submit`.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_submit', 'add_prepayment' )
function add_prepayment() {
  echo '<p><label><input type="checkbox" name="pre_payment">Pay partially</label></p>';
}
```

[image: Checkbox option for pre-payment before proceeding to wc payment gateways]
The plan is to make the order total price half when the user checked the "Pay Partially" option.

Are there wc filter or action hooks so that I can modify the amount to charge before sending it to a payment gateway?

Comment: As this is quite very advanced and complicated (a real development)… Just searching (first match): [WooCommerce Deposits - Partial Payments Plugin](https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-deposits-partial-payments-plugin/9249233) … I haven't test it, so at your own risk, but it seem serious.

Answer (score 0):

Just got lucky. After hours of searching through woocommerce plugin code, I found this filter hook: `woocommerce_paypal_args`
So what I did is:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_paypal_args', 'paypal_args' );
function paypal_args( $order ) {
        $partial_payment = isset( $_REQUEST[ 'partial_payment' ] ) ? $_REQUEST[ 'partial_payment' ] : false;

        if( $partial_payment ) {
            $current_price  = $order['amount_1'];
            // Some calculation process here..
            $order['amount_1'] = $new_price;
        }

        return $order;
  }
```

By the way, thank you everyone.